# Dataframe with arrays and key-pairs

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON structure which I need to convert it into data-frame. I have converted through pandas library but I am having issues in two columns where one is an array and the other one is key-pair value.

```
         Pito                                   Value
{"pito-key": "Number"}             [{"WRITESTAMP": "2018-06-28T16:30:36Z", "S":"41bbc22","VALUE":"2"}]
```

How to break columns into the data-frames.

Comment: Please provide a sample from `json` file and the desired output for that sample. Also provide how you read the json.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you can apply regular expressions to do that.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'pito':['{"pito-key": "Number"}'], 'value':['[{"WRITESTAMP": "2018-06-28T16:30:36Z", "S":"41bbc22","VALUE":"2"}]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_value(s):
    s = s[1]
    v = re.findall(r'VALUE\":\".*\"', s)
    return int(v[0][8:-1])

def get_pito(s):
    s = s[0]
    v = re.findall(r'key\": \".*\"', s)
    return v[0][7:-1]

df['value'] = df.apply(get_value, axis=1)
df['pito'] = df.apply(get_pito, axis=1)
df.head()
```

Here I create 2 functions that transform your scary strings to values you want them to have

Let me know if that's not what you meant